# How to adjust the datatype in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, types

I practiced the MulitIndex function in pandas, but, it does not work as I expected. I think it is because my fundamental knowledge is not enough.

```
from StringIO import StringIO # io.StringIO on python 3.X
import pandas as pd

datacsv = StringIO("""\
date,id,a,b
20150209,42366,7644,6366
20150209,52219,2741,1796
20150209,52831,163,145
20150209,53209,1047,862
20150209,53773,31343,22501
20150209,58935,16621,14873
20150209,65464,19838,12177
20150209,65823,4903,2982
20150209,68497,16564,12207
20150209,79230,48714,37355
20150208,42366,7644,6366
20150208,52219,2741,1796
20150208,52831,163,145
20150208,53209,1047,862
20150208,53773,31343,22501
20150208,58935,16621,14873
20150208,65464,19838,12177
20150208,65823,4903,2982
20150208,68497,16564,12207
20150208,79230,48714,37355"
""")

df = pd.read_csv(datacsv)
df = df.set_index(['date','id']
```

The current 'date' is note datetime. How to transfer the type of 'date' into datetime such as 2015-02-09?

Comment: Hey. Good question. I hope you don't mind, but I added the data from your link to the question itself. The reason is that link die and get moved. So having the data here ensures that the question will remain useful to other in the future. Also, it serves as a good demonstration to you and others on how to make a simple and reproducible example for pandas questions.

Comment: @PaulH I did not notice that you added the data. And, I rewrote the post. Could you help to add again since I have no idea to use your way to perform the data.

Comment: just look at the the question's edit history. My revision should be available there.

Comment: @PaulH Your revision is there. But, nothing changed when I pick up your.....It seems that I am not good at using stackoverflow = =

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a Series (or column) to datetime using `pd.to_datetime` and specifying the format.

For instance a Series of integers like the dates in your CSV file can be converted like this:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([20150207, 20150208, 20150209])
>>> pd.to_datetime(s, format="%Y%m%d")
0   2015-02-07
1   2015-02-08
2   2015-02-09
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So to change the date column before you set the index, you could write:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why perform the datetime conversion after loading when you can just pass the column name to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) for the param `parse_dates`:

```
In [30]:

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), parse_dates=['date'])
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 20 entries, 0 to 19
Data columns (total 4 columns):
date    20 non-null datetime64[ns]
id      20 non-null int64
a       20 non-null int64
b       20 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(3)
```

Additionally you can specify which column should be treated as the index so you can perform the datetime conversion and set the index as params to `read_csv`, just set `parse_dates` and `index_col`:

```
In [34]:

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), parse_dates=['date'], index_col=['date'])
type(df.index)
Out[34]:
pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```